# Does Redshift support java.sql.DatabaseMetaData?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to use `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData` to find out about what tables exist on a redshift cluster.

`ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, "public", "mytable", null);`

returns nothing, even though I can see that the table exists.

I've hunted for documentation about whether Redshift supports `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData` but I can't find any.

I am using the latest driver

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
    <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.10.1009</version>
</dependency>
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Mystery solved. It seems that it was a question of upper and lower case.

When I created my table, it had some upper case in it - `MY_table` and

`select * from MY_table`

worked fine.

But internally redshift stored the table name as `my_table`, all lowercase, so I wasn't getting a match when trying to find `MY_table`